# Error when trying to connect Metamask to Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, metamask, unity-webgl

I'm developing a decentralised videogame using Unity. To connect Unity to Metamask I'm using a library called Web3GL.
When I try to connect my account to Metamask this message pops-up[image]
I've been experiencing this problem for a long time now and I really don't know what to do about this! The fun part is that when I try to build and run directly from Unity it works but when I embed the game inside my webpage I receive this pop up.
Does anyone know how to help me?

The error points me to library code that I've never touched so I don't think I've created the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem caused by encoding issues. You're probably using Brotli encoding in your WebGL builds **(Build -> Player Settings -> Publishing Settings -> Compression Format)**. And it's known that somehow in local servers without HTTPS, this error may persist. (I'll investigate more and edit my answer including the reason in the future, hopefully). In order to get rid of the issue you may **disable Brotli encoding** or **turn on Decompression Fallback** in Publishing Settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue and there is open ticket regard it already
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-sdk/issues/154

You need to use android version 6.6.0 app , the latest update trigger this bug